# Modifying a copy of a Collection from with a For Each still gives error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to scan through some True/False RadioButtonLists that I have.  They're within an  QuestionsList.  I am trying to add a message to each item saying "Correct" or "Incorrect", but when I do so I get "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If (IsPostBack) Then
        Dim SubmittedQuestionsList As New HtmlGenericControl("ol")
        SubmittedQuestionsList = QuestionsList

        For Each QuestionItem In SubmittedQuestionsList.Controls
            If TypeOf QuestionItem Is HtmlGenericControl Then
                For Each question In QuestionItem.Controls
                    If TypeOf question Is RadioButtonList Then
                        Dim QuestionExplanation As New Panel
                        If (question.SelectedValue = "true") Then
                            QuestionExplanation.CssClass = "succcess-response"
                            QuestionExplanation.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("Correct!"))
                        Else
                            QuestionExplanation.CssClass = "error-response"
                            QuestionExplanation.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("Incorrect:"))
                        End If
                        'If I uncomment the line below, error goes away
                        QuestionsList.Controls.Add(QuestionExplanation)
                        Debug.WriteLine(question.SelectedValue)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

What is the best way to loop through it (or a copy of it), and add a message as I go?

Comment: SubmittedQuestionsList is just another reference to the same QuestionsList.  Either use a clone of QuestionsList, use a For loop instead of For Each, or track which items to modify and modify them in a separate loop.

Comment: I thought SubmittedQuestionsList was a clone of QuestionsList... do you know how to properly clone it instead of just referencing it?

Comment: I think it should be more performant to add the controls to an intermediate array and then use a single call to Controls.AddRange() at the end of the loop. That would have the desired side effect of not changing the collection within your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Per Dave's comment, noting that SubmittedQuestionsList was simply a reference to QuestionsList, I found I could simply use an Array.

Replace:

```
Dim SubmittedQuestionsList As New HtmlGenericControl("ol")
SubmittedQuestionsList = QuestionsList
```

with:

```
Dim SubmittedQuestionsList(QuestionsList.Controls.Count) As HtmlGenericControl
QuestionsList.Controls.CopyTo(SubmittedQuestionsList, 0)
```